# Alternatives for BitLocker technology

Tags: external-hard-drive, bitlocker

I am looking for a program that can encrypt external hard disk and doesn't need third party application to decrypt.

All I found is BitLocker but the problem is that I don't have pro version of windows so I don't have access to this feature.

I am curios to know if there are alternative technology available for this purpose.

Comment: Hi WOEITG, questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic, you might look if your question fits for [softwarerecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I asked to move the question to other forum

Comment: Indeed softwarerecs as migration path would be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...and doesn't need third party application to decrypt." How to do that without a programm? Try [VeraCrypt in portable mode](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Portable%20Mode).

Comment: thanks for answer.have you ever tried this method? How long does it takes to decrypt ?

Comment: @WOEITG - How long it takes to decrypt depends on the size of the HDD.  The only way you can encrypt an external HDD on Windows is to either use Bitlocker or to use a third-party program.  Since you can't use BItlocker that means your limited to a third-party program.